# Arduino Uno with UsbSerial Android library w/ baud rate over 9600?

Tags: android, baud-rate

I am having no issues talking to Android at baud rate of 9600. But once I raise the baud rate to anything higher Android seems to become deaf. When I try to read the Serial output using putty all seems fine.

Has anyone had success with baud rate over 9600 when talking to Android?

I am using the [felHR85/UsbSerial](https://github.com/felHR85/UsbSerial) library.

Answer (score 1):

I have no enough reputations to make a comment so I will drop my two cents here.

Are you changing the baudrate at both sides?

I have been using the arduino's built-in UART library for a while using different baudrates with no problems. Your problem could be an issue related to the library you are using.

Comment: Yes sir, I set the same speed on both sides. On Arduino I use the default Serial library too. The issue probably lies on the Android side.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there is [a bug](https://github.com/felHR85/UsbSerial/issues/91) in the library.